# Message passing by chrome.runtime.sendMessage()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I refered the chrome documentation https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#type-MessageSender as well as https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage

In my sample chrome extension, I would like to pass a number from **contentscript.js** to **popup.js**:

**contentscript.js:**

```
var fromDOM = 100;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({fromDOM});//here I'm passing value in fromDOM
```

**popup.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response){

  number = response; //here I'm assigning value in response to total

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=number;//manipulating an element
                                                    // in popup.html
}
);
```

The element "output" isn't getting modified.

So, am I doing everything right? How should "any message" parameter be in general and can I use that parameter this way?

**Updated my contenscript.js and background.js:**

**contenscript.js:**

```
//code to get values from a table in results page
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse")[0];

var marks = new Array();

 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   marks[i] = table.children[0].children[i+1].children[5].innerHTML;

 var total=0;
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   total += Number(marks[i]);


var fromDOM = total;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(fromDOM);
```

**background.js:**

```
//code to display pageaction button on domain results.griet.in
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: {
                        hostSuffix:<website>
                    }
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
});

//code to inject contentscript.
chrome.tabs.executeScript({"file": "contentscript.js"});
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is invalid. Change `{fromDOM}` to `fromDOM`.

Comment: Yep, changed it but still the same thing @Rob W

Comment: Make sure that the popup is active when you're running the content script.

Comment: Yes, buddy , it is active I suppose. I updated my scripts, please do check them dude.

Comment: In your current code, you're just running the content script once at start-up. You should actually insert the content script from your popup.js, and handle the response over there.